# jQuery height change not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, css-transitions

I have a JS feature on the following site that is working just fine in Firefox but not in Safari: http://rossbolger.com/kids/light-stories/

The feature slides out a grid of thumbnails called **#image-thumbs** when the mouse hovers over the container called **#hit-area**. It works (at least in Firefox) by first changing #image_thumbs height from '48px' to 'auto', the height is then measured using jQuery's height(). This height is stored in a variable and then using jQuery's css() it is given back to the #image-thumbs when the mouse is over.

The code on the site looks a little something like this:

```
// Thumbnails Nav Reveal and Hide Scripts
var thumbs_height = 1,
thumbs = $('#image-thumbs'),
thumbs_original_height = thumbs.css('height');

// Slide Up Thumbs
(function revealThumbs() {

    // On hover let the thumbs become their full height
    $('#image-thumbs #hit-area').hover(function(){ // Mouse over
        // Get the unrestricted height of the thumbs
        thumbs.css('height', 'auto');
        thumbs_height =  thumbs.height();

        // then put it back to what it was so we can animate it using CSS3 transition
        thumbs.css('height', 'inherit');

        // delay 0.1s before triggering the change in height (time for the calculations to complete)
        setTimeout( function() { thumbs.css('height', thumbs_height ) }, 100 );

    }, function(){ // Mouse out
        hideThumbs();
    });
})();

// Hide thumbs
function hideThumbs(){
    thumbs.css('height', thumbs_original_height );
};
```

The reason for measuring the unrestricted height and passing it back as a pixel value, rather than simply setting the height to 'auto', is to create a sliding effect via CSS3 (i.e. transition: height 0.5s). The transition only takes place if the affected attribute goes from one numeric value to another.

Thanks for any help bug testing this. I haven't even looked at other browsers yet.

All the best,
Laurence

Comment: Could it be to do with the scope of the variables? Just found that the console in Safari considers 'thumbs' in hideThumbs() as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've worked it out...

In the javascript document (scripts.js on the site) there was a function higher up the page calling the hideThumbs() function. So it wasn't working because the variables in hideThumbs() hadn't been declared at that point. Funny that it should still work in Firefox and IE9!

I've moved all this code to a point before that other function and the problem is now resolved. *So far I've only done this locally. I'll update the site in the link above later.*